# Align button and text in collapse Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I try to use the element [Collapse in Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) but i have i little problem.

This is an image for exemple [image]

I try to align my text an my button trash in the same line.
As you can see it's shifted.

how to solve this problem?

```
<form method="post" action="wbx.php">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="submit" name="supprAlias" value="'.$idValue.'">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Anim pariatur cliche...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2</a>
                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="submit" name="supprAlias" value="'.$idValue.'">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                </button>

            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    Anim pariatur cliche...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my Controler in another page :

```
if(!empty($_POST['supprUserAlias']))
{
    $savant->deletesUserAlias = $gemel->setDeleteUserAlias($_POST['supprUserAlias'], $username, $domain, $serverMail);
    header('Location: wbx.php?user='.$username.'#alias');
    exit;
}
```

EDIT

Finally find the solution :

Pu the `<button>` betweeen `<div class="accordion-group">` and `<div class="accordion-heading">`

```
<form method="post" action="wbx.php">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                   <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="submit" name="supprAlias" value="'.$idValue.'">
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            </button>
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                        Anim pariatur cliche...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code to please?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the button inside the link (a) tag like this. I think you should also make the button smaller (`btn-mini`) so that it fits nicely inside the collapse link.

```
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
    Collapsible Group Item #1 <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right" type="submit"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></button>
</a>
```

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://bootply.com/62042)</kbd>

*EDIT-*

The click of the button can be handled like..

```
$('.accordion-toggle .btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("button!");
    return false;
})
```

Comment: no ! who can i click on the button an execute an action if the button is in the <a> and just  unroll the collapse ?

Comment: That can handled using a click function on the button. I updated the demo http://bootply.com/62042